# How to sort array in constant time in java and python?

Tags: java, python, arrays, sorting

I was trying to learn algos and data structures, and i was wondering about best approach to sort arrays in constant time.

I am newbie but my only intention is to get insight on this very fundamental thing to get familiar with how things work.

Or if anyone can add value to my question or on my knowledge of problem solving

Comment: This is an opion based answer and not suitable for SO.

Comment: Sorry for sounding stupid, I am newbie but my only intention was to get insight on this very fundamental things to get familiar with how things work

Comment: Any good reason why this is marked both java and python when no code from either language is involved?

Comment: I have a good grip in those languages and I expected an already existing package/util /inbuilt function in either of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if arrays could be sorted in constant time, the world will change for good.

As per my knowledge, the lowest time a sorting algorithm can sort in linear O(n) like count sort which is inefficient for data with large values.

You should try understanding what exactly does time in a time complexity indicate; that'll give you an idea of your question and how and why it's not possible as of now.

The best you can get as of now are Merge Sort and Quick Sort with O(nlogn) time complexity which are efficient.

Comment: Yeah I have good idea of Time Complexities but I was looking for an ultimate solution to this very basic problem

Comment: As of today, it doesn't exist. Quantam Computing might make it possible in future but that's unknown.

Comment: Even Quantum computing cant sort an array in constant time. Ω(NlogN) is the best quantum comp can do with our current understanding. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-quantum-sorting-algorithms